# Compile a remotely cpoied project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sln-file, vcproj

I have got a project code containing the .sln and .vcproj files. The goal is to compile it on my system. For sure when I open .sln file in visual studio, due to the signatures of the path of the original system (where I obtained files) it would not run and compile on my system.
What is the way to change path inside all those files and not to go inside each one and manually change them?
Say, files on original system was in D:\... while now on mine are in C:\...

Comment: Either ask the person who wrote that code to change it for you, or change it yourself .. There's not much else to do. This was a bad idea in the first place, so now either one of you need to fix it.